# Handle maybe in do block and extract a value

Tags: haskell

I'm reading a yaml which results in a maybe:

```
main :: IO ()
main = 
  do 
     justConfig <- decodeFile "config.yaml" :: IO (Maybe Config)
     case justConfig of
       Just config -> initState $ config
       Nothing -> initState $ (Map.fromList [("hi", "bye")])
```

How would you extract the result of initState from:

```
do      
  Just config ... 
  state <- initState $ config
```

Comment: What is your question? Please describe a specific problem you're facing.

Comment: You can use a nested `do` block like any other expression, but you need to make sure you use it in a context where the resulting type is expected. What do you want to *do* with the result of `initState`? (Note that you can ditch the `case` expression; just write `config <- fromMaybe defaultConfig  <$> decodeFile "config.yaml"`, where `defaultConfig` is the `Map` you pass in the `Nothing` case.

Comment: What module do you use for `initState`?

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re asking but since `case` is just an expression, which here seems to return an `IO` action, you can use it as the right side of a bind statement, e.g. `state <- case … of …`. If `initState` is pure, use a `let` block instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a nested `do` block which uses a different monad, but you need to ensure it is used where the resulting monadic type is expected. For example, suppose you have a function `foo :: StateMonad Foo -> IO ()`. Then you can write the following, assuming `initState :: Config -> StateMonad State`.

```
main = do -- IO monad
   let defaultConfig = Map.fromList [("hi", "bye")]
   config <- fromMaybe defaultConfig <$> decodeFile "config.yaml"
   foo $ do -- StateMonad monad
     state <- initState config  -- initState config :: StateMonad State
                                -- state :: State
     ...
     return x  -- x :: Foo
```